# Click event to highlight text

Tags: tkinter, highlight, python-3.7

How do I create an event that allows a user to highlight text by left-clicking and dragging?

I am new to programming. So far I have tried simplifying it by having just a single left click on a word highlight that word but I think there is a problem with my tag_bind() function.

```
import wx
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def text_click_callback(event):
    # an event to highlight a line when single click is done
    line_no = event.widget.index("@%s,%s linestart" % (event.x, 
event.y))
    #print(line_no)
    line_end = event.widget.index("%s lineend" % line_no)
    event.widget.tag_remove("highlight", 1.0, "end")
    event.widget.tag_add("highlight", line_no, line_end)
    event.widget.tag_configure("highlight", background="yellow")

File_object = open(r"Recall Tests.txt", "r")


m = PanedWindow(root)
m.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


text1 = Text(m, height=90, width=90)
m.add(text1)
fileList = File_object.readlines()
text1.insert(INSERT, ''.join(fileList))
text1.config(state=DISABLED)

text1.tag_bind(text1, "highlight", text_click_callback)



text2 = Text(m, height=90, width=90, highlightcolor="black")
m.add(text2)
Label_1 = tk.Label(text2, text="NOTES",fg="red", font="Ariel 16 
underline").grid(row=4, column=0)
Label_2 = tk.Label(text2, text="PID:").grid(row=1)
e1 = tk.Entry(text2, width=90)
e1.grid(row=1, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

This opens up a text file on the left and a text box on the right. I want the user to be able to highlight sentences that are displayed on the text file by left-clicking and dragging their mouse. I am trying to have the click function work first but when the file opens, a left click does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the left click doesn't work is that you've bound it to a tag, and when the program starts up, nothing has that tag.

If you want the click to work anywhere in the text, use `bind` rather than `tag_bind`:

```
text1.bind("<B1>", text_click_callback)
```

If you want the highlight as the user drags the mouse, you'll need to bind to `<B1-Motion>`

```
text1.bind("<B1>", text_click_callback)
```